# How do I do backreferences correctly in Objective-C with NSRegularExpression?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

In PHP I'd do something like this:

[image]

But in Objective-C, I tried this:

```
    regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\.([a-zA-Z0-9])" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    result = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:result options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [result length]) withTemplate:@". \1"];
```

But it ends up simply removing the first letter of the next sentence (such as "end. Chris" -> "end. hris"). Why is this?

Comment: Side note - you do realize that if there is a decimal number in the text, you will end up adding a space to the number.

Comment: Which Application is that of the snapshot???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$1`, `$2`, etc. instead of `\1`, `\2`, etc. for back references.

See the docs for `NSRegularExpression`. Look under the "Template Matching Format" section.

Comment: It says \n. http://i.imgur.com/3WTiPRo.png https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Look under the "Template Matching Format".

Comment: Fair enough, but why does it say that?

Comment: You use `\n` in the search pattern, you use `$n` in the replacement (template).